# How can i retrieve the error code from a function ran remotely via ssh in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Here's a simple script I have to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
ssh -x user@remote-host "
function wtf
{
    rm /
}; wtf"

wait
```

And then I run it like this in the commandline:

```
> if ./wtf.sh; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
rm: cannot remove '\': Is a directory
yes
```

Obviously the `rm` command failed, but `wtf.sh` succeeded. I would like for `wtf.sh` to also return a negative exit so I can detect it. How can I do that?

Comment: Your function tries to remove '/', but the error message mentions '\'. Which is the typo?

Comment: What is printing "yes"? If `ssh` completes before you actually call `wait`, `wait`'s exit code will be 0, regardless of the outcome of `ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$?` which holds the return code of the most recently executed command. Possibly your actual script is not as simple as the example (hence the `wait`). The variable `retval` stores the return code from the wtf function and the value is returned from the script.

```
ssh -x user@remote-host "
function wtf
{
    rm /
    return $?
}; wtf; return $?"

wait
```

Comment: This gives me: ./wtf.sh: line 10: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the script. By the way, do you need define the function on the local side?

Comment: Yes I do, in part to self contain the job and avoid another script. I plugged the retun retval statement you metioned into the above script not the real one and it gives me that error

Comment: You need to use single quotes for the command string; otherwise, `$?` will be expanded locally and its value will be sent to the remote host instead.

Comment: @chepner but what if I want other variables to be expanded locally in the function command string?

Comment: Then you need to escape the dollar sign: `return \$?` inside the double quotes.